# Microsoft Excel Conditional Formatting Not Equal To Value/Blanks

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have information in column B and C. I want column C to be formatted RED when it is NOT equal to "connected" and NOT blank.  I have it currently working in a sort of cheap way where I have ordered 3 different conditions.

```
Rule 1 - ="Connected" color green
Rule 2 - =BLANK color white
Rule 3 - <>"Connected color red
```

This only works due to the ordering..I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish rules 2 and 3 in one set of code.  I want this applied to entire C column, =$C:$C

Comment: try `=AND($C1<>"", $C1<>"Connected")` or `=AND(LEN($C1), $C1<>"Connected")`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work if cell C1 is = Connected.

Comment: You wanted full column CF so the formula has to involve C1. Add another condition to the AND that excludes row 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column C is white to start with, select it then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=C1="connected"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green, OK, OK.

Then repeat for red with:

```
 =AND(C1<>"",C1<>"connected")
```